# Unable to log in to IIS Application

Tags: iis, iis-10

I have been facing a very weird issue with a simple web application that I have recently deployed using IIS. This is an already working application in a server in NA region. I re-created the same exact IIS environment in a new server from a different region. When I try to login using the new URL, I get the following error message.

[image: Error Message]

I have double-checked multiple times that my IIS configuration is exactly same as my old (working) server.

Here is what I have selected for the Authentication setting of the server.
[image]

Kindly help with the pointers. Thank you.

Comment: From your posting, I did not see the error message.

Comment: Of course you found nothing wrong on server side, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/prompt-for-username-and-password because the prompt is purely a browser side behavior.